# How can I check returned value from put request angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular material stepper, and after each step I send data to backend. So, I have this method in me fist step, that return LeadStatusRequest the following kind:

```
export interface LeadStatusRequest {
    id: number;
    value: string;
    publicId: string;
}
```

and put method:

```
public submit(): Observable<LeadStatusRequest> {
    return this.dataService
        .putData(this.formData)
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                const emailErrorText: string =
                    'Email address already exists. No update performed';
                if (err.error.Errors.find(error => error.includes(emailErrorText))) {
                    this.formGroup.controls.emailAddress.setErrors({notUniqueEmail: true});
                    return throwError({isSkippedNotification: true});
                }
                return throwError(err);
            }),
        );
}
```

So I should check if the result of submit method returns object with key "publicId", I should set it to localstorage.
I try do this, but in this case I have a several put requests

```
public submit(): Observable<LeadStatusRequest> {
        this.dataService.putData(this.formData)
            .subscribe(res => {
            if (res.publicId) {
                this.authService.setPublicId(res.publicId);
            }
        });
        return this.dataService
            .putData(this.formData)
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    const emailErrorText: string =
                        'Email address already exists. No update performed';
                    if (err.error.Errors.find(error => error.includes(emailErrorText))) {
                        this.formGroup.controls.emailAddress.setErrors({notUniqueEmail: true});
                        return throwError({isSkippedNotification: true});
                    }
                    return throwError(err);
                }),
            )
    }
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: You have several requests ... so where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to:

- Make 1 `this.dataService.putData` call
- Take some conditional action based on a success response
- Handle a failed response

Your `catchError` operator will only run if there is an error. All you need to do is handle the success response in an operator before `catchError`. You can perform actions using the `tap` operator.

```js
public submit(): Observable<LeadStatusRequest> {
  return this.dataService
    .putData(this.formData)    
    .pipe(
      tap(res => {
        if (res.publicId) {
          this.authService.setPublicId(res.publicId);
        }
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        const emailErrorText: string = 'Email address already exists. No update performed';
        if (err.error.Errors.find(error => error.includes(emailErrorText))) {
          this.formGroup.controls.emailAddress.setErrors({notUniqueEmail: true});
          return throwError({isSkippedNotification: true});
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
}
```